# SQL- A query doesn't show me data

Tags: sql, select

I have a table people with fields "id" "name" and "p_father"
I want to select records where the "id" field does not appear in the column "p_father"

I try this query

```
select * from people where (id  not in (select p_father from people));
```

But this doesn't show me any results. However if I use this query

```
select * from people where (id  in (select p_father from people));
```

It shows me all the records except the one I wanna select

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some sample data, and what the expected results should be.

Comment: maybe one of your p_father is `null`? See this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b9de6/2